# xpages extension library dialog update data table

Tags: dialog, xpages, panel

I have a xpages page that has a data table in a panel that calls an extension library dialog whose function is to create documents that are displayed in that data table. I would like to know if there is any way to by pressing the button to close the dialog refresh the data table with the new documents created.

Comment: I was able to make put the refresh put through the command below in the onComplete event of the dialog button that closes it.

XSP.partialRefreshGet(idPanel)

Answer (score 0):

I've used what's mentioned here to achieve that in the past:

[XPages:dialog box refreshing a panel on close](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30381513/xpagesdialog-box-refreshing-a-panel-on-close)

Comment: I tried, by this method, but it is not even closing the dialog, so it does not update the data table

Comment: Have you changed the .hide("panel") that you mention in response to Howard to just be .hide()? Are you getting anything printed to the server log?

Answer (score 0):

Use a parameter in the .hide method to specify a control to refresh when closing the dialog.  https://www-10.lotus.com/ldd/ddwiki.nsf/xpDocViewer.xsp?lookupName=Domino+Designer+XPages+Extension+Library#action=openDocument&res_title=Modal_dialogs_ddxl853&content=pdcontent

Comment: I tried, by this method, but it is not even closing the dialog, so it does not update the data table. I just managed to close the window with the CSJS command dijit.byId ("# {id: dialog1}"). Hide ("panel"), however it is not updating the data table.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to close the dialog box and update the data table as follows:

In the onClick event on the client side, and I put the code:

```
Dijit.byId ("# {id: dialogboxname}"). Hide ("panelWithDataTable")
```

And in the onComplete event of the button I use the code below:

```
Var idPanel = '# {id: panelWithDataTable}';
XSP.partialRefreshGet (idPanel)
```